# Definite Integration by parts

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

how do I code

```
Integrate[u[x] D[v[x], x], {x, a, b}]
```

to return the following straightforward undergraduate result?

```
u[b] v[b] - u[a] v[a] - Integrate[v[x] D[u[x], x], {x, a, b}]
```

Comment: You don't. In fact, you should perhaps abandon attempts to achieve that. Integration-by-computer is carried out very differently from work done by hand.

Comment: Could always define your own little scheme, `intbyparts[u_,dv_,a_,b_]=...` if you feel up to the task. Need to make sure `dv` would be pretty easily integrable though.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html)

```
WolframAlpha["integration by parts (mathematical problem)", \
{{"FormulasPod:FamousMathProblem", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's a resource function, based on the the internal utility `` ResourceFunctionHelpers`IntegrateByParts ``:

```
ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"][
 u[x] D[v[x], x], {x, a, b}]
```

[image]

```
ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"][
 u[x] D[v[x], x], {x, a, b}, "Grid"]
```

[image]